# Migrating Azure Functions for version 3.x with Gradle Java project, but "Value cannot be null" error

Tags: java, azure, gradle, azure-function-app

Hi I have a gradle Java project that uses Azure functions and we are migration from version 2.x to version 3.x. Logically , I wanted to increase the version to 3.x locally and test to make sure nothing breaks, however, I am getting an error (*I will post the full error message at the end of this post because it is much longer*):

```
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1').
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
Application is shutting down...
```

Now, the super weird thing, is in the error message (I show it in the longer version down below), it has a link for the extension bundle where some index.json is. If I click-it and open it in my browser, immediately after that, I can run ./gradlew azureFunctionsRun locally and everything will work fine:
Looking for extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle at (null)
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] Fetching information on versions of extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle available on https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/index.json

This doesn't really make any sense to me, but upon more research, it seemed someone else posted saying that if the ExtensionBundle takes too long to download, the Azure runtime will crash/fail/won't start properly:

https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/Azure/azure-functions-host/4959/593681079

Is anyone here familiar with Azure Functions and/or has migrated to version 3.x or a higher version? On Microsoft's website, they seem to only mention upgrading and what variables to edit when using Maven Java project (I am using Gradle):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions

Furthermore,  I did find documentation revolving around Azure functions and Gradle on github, but some of the commands they suggested didn't seem to work i.e. adding an "appSettings" property in the build.gradle with FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = ~3:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions-Gradle-Plugin-(Preview)

If it means anything, this is what my **host.json** file looks like:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

and my **local.settings.json**:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3"
  }
}
```

If anyone has some insight, I would greatly appreciate it. I can also post any bits of my build.gradle that anyone would like to see. Thank you.

```
Full error messsage:
Azure Functions Core Tools (3.0.2106 Commit hash: 5431fca4f603bf9446d7dd2d5f96a43b5f69b5cb)
Function Runtime Version: 3.0.13107
[3/9/2020 6:25:11 PM] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to java. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:node
[3/9/2020 6:25:11 PM] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to java. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:powershell
[3/9/2020 6:25:11 PM] FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to java. Skipping WorkerConfig for language:python
[3/9/2020 6:25:11 PM] Starting worker process:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java  -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar "C:\Users\KBRV37\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin
\workers\java\azure-functions-java-worker.jar" --host 127.0.0.1 --port 53364 --workerId 0f9b1658-9070-47d5-9175-927c2de3b987 --requestId 0d91a6fb-436a-4747-84cb-1b452b6f5d74 --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[3/9/2020 6:25:11 PM] C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241\bin\java process with Id=17808 started
[3/9/2020 6:25:11 PM] [INFO] {Application.main}: Azure Functions Java Worker  version [ 1.5.2-SNAPSHOT]
[3/9/2020 6:25:12 PM] [INFO] {MessageHandler.handle}: Message generated by "StartStream.Builder"
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] Building host: startup suppressed: 'False', configuration suppressed: 'False', startup operation id: '578d2375-a458-44f0-837c-7d165eb8ed5a'
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] Reading host configuration file 'C:\git\edge_bootstrap_ms\build\azurefunctions\edge-bootstrap-ms\host.json'
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] Host configuration file read:
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] {
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM]   "version": "2.0",
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM]   "extensionBundle": {
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM]     "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM]     "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM]   }
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] }
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] Reading functions metadata
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] 3 functions found
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] Looking for extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle at (null)
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] Fetching information on versions of extension bundle Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle available on https://functionscdn.azureedge.net/public/ExtensionBundles/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/index.json
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] A host error has occurred during startup operation '578d2375-a458-44f0-837c-7d165eb8ed5a'.
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] System.Private.CoreLib: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'path1').
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
Application is shutting down...
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] Initialization cancellation requested by runtime.
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] Shutting down language worker channels for runtime:java
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] Stopping host...
[3/9/2020 6:25:13 PM] Host shutdown completed.

> Task :azureFunctionsRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':azureFunctionsRun'.
> Process 'command 'cmd.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```